# Can I put a SELECT query into the IF statement in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

Well, I am getting some values from the main table say `MTB` and summarising it in some another table say `STB` using this script. There is no Unique or Primary key so I can't use ON DUPLICATE KEY situation here.

What I want to do is if the node name) fetched from the `MTB` Already exists in the `STB` Then I just want to update it and if the node name from `MTB` does not exist in the `STB` then I want to insert the data into the table.

I tried using the If case by first selecting the row in the `STB` using the nodename fetched from the `MTB` that if the nodename from the `MTB` is present in `STB` (i.e Select query IS NOT NULL) then We Update it else We insert it.

However, this fails to work. Kindly suggest that what I have done wrong.

```
IF (SELECT * FROM `NodesInfo` WHERE `Nodename` = '".$row2['nodeName']."') IS NOT NULL 

    THEN
        UPDATE `NodesInfo` SET `Time Stamp`= '".$row2['timeStamp']."',`Status`= '$status' WHERE `Nodename` = '".$row2['nodeName']."'

ELSE 

    INSERT INTO `NodesInfo`(`Nodename`, `Category`, `Time Stamp`, `Type`, `Status`) VALUES ('".$row2['nodeName']."','NodeMCUMQTTData','".$row2['timeStamp']."','$type','$status') 

END IF
```

Comment: In mysql you can only use this kind of if statement in store programs (procedure,function,event,triggers)

Comment: What error are using in query ?

Comment: Is (SELECT ...) IS NOT NULL i think it should be EXISTS (SELECT ...)?

Comment: See INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY...

Comment: @P.Salmon Okay i will try this using procedure

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad On executing this using mysqli_query() i have added an if else with echo statement whether this runs or not and it doesnt on phpmyadmin it is saying incorrect syntax

Comment: @Lee Initially i tried EXISTS also but that too isnt working , I myself found it strange however i will try to run it using procedure maybe then it can work

Comment: @Strawberry for using ON DUPLICATE KEY we need a unique or primary key that it can check for existing entries however in my table I dont having any primary or unique key coulumn and so it cant work in my case :(

Comment: `$row2['nodeName']` seems like you are using php. Maybe you could check the existance of the entry in a separate query before and then do the update or insert depending on that?

Comment: If you don't have a unique/primary key, then you don't really have a table, which puts the problem beyond the present scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at the following code, it works.
For MYSQL :

```
$qry = mysqli_query(<set your db connection variable>, "SELECT * FROM `NodesInfo` WHERE nodeName` = '".$row2['nodeName']."' ");
$res = mysqli_num_rows($qry);

if($res > 0)
{
    $update_qry = mysqli_query(<set your db connection variable>, "UPDATE `NodesInfo` SET `Time Stamp`= '".$row2['timeStamp']."',`Status`= '$status' WHERE nodeName` = '".$row2['nodeName']."'");
}
else
{
    $insert_qry = mysqli_query(<set your db connection variable>, "INSERT INTO `NodesInfo`(`Nodename`, `Category`, `Time Stamp`, `Type`, `Status`) VALUES ('".$row2['nodeName']."','NodeMCUMQTTData','".$row2['timeStamp']."','$type','$status')");
}
```

Comment: Yes this works , also I noted that in the query I forgot ' ` ' this in the Where clause around Node Name ...Damn... Still thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to update `nodeName` if it already exits otherwise inserts a new entry.

To achieve this, you can make your `nodeName` field unique.

```
ALTER TABLE `NodesInfo` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `idx_nodeName` (`nodeName`);
```

Now you can try [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/)

```
INSERT INTO `NodesInfo`(`Nodename`, `Category`, `Time Stamp`, `Type`, `Status`) VALUES ('".$row2['nodeName']."',
'NodeMCUMQTTData',
'".$row2['timeStamp']."',
'$type','$status'
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`Time Stamp`= '".$row2['timeStamp']."',
`Status`= '$status';
```

Comment: I know that but i can't make it unique due to some constrains :(

Answer (score 0):

```
IF exists(SELECT * FROM `NodesInfo` WHERE nodeName` = '".$row2['nodeName']."') 

  THEN
   UPDATE `NodesInfo` SET `Time Stamp`= '".$row2['timeStamp']."',`Status`= '$status' WHERE nodeName` = '".$row2['nodeName']."'

ELSE 

    INSERT INTO `NodesInfo`(`Nodename`, `Category`, `Time Stamp`, `Type`, `Status`) VALUES ('".$row2['nodeName']."','NodeMCUMQTTData','".$row2['timeStamp']."','$type','$status') 

END IF
```

Comment: Tried previously and tried again , still not working